# how to submit an array of objects in formik?

Tags: javascript, redux, formik

I'm trying to create a gym app where I can submit a few exercises and call this a "workout". Ive got it working to a certain point but it falls over because my object is named and not anonymous which makes it hard to be scalable

```
    <Formik
      initialValues={''}
      onSubmit={values => {this.props.submitExercise(values)}}
      render={() => (
        <Form>
          {this.state.exercises.map((exercise, index) => (
            <div>
              {console.log(exercise, 'ex')}
              <label htmlFor="exercise">Exercise</label>
              <Field name={`exercise${index}.name`} />

              <label htmlFor="reps">Reps</label>
              <Field name={`exercise${index}.reps`} type="number" />

              <label htmlFor="sets">Sets</label>
              <Field name={`exercise${index}.sets`} type="number" />

              <label htmlFor="weight">Weight</label>
              <Field name={`exercise${index}.weight`} type="number" />
            </div>
          ))}
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </Form>
      )}
    />


export const submitExercise = workout => {
  console.log(workout) // workout here is coming through as {exercise0: {...}}
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'SUBMIT_EXERCISE', workout })
    // dispatch(saveStateToServer(getState().workouts))
  }
}
```

I am wondering the best way I can fill in say X amount of exercises. each with a name, reps, set, weight etc. as an object and then they come through as an array. currently it's coming through with a hardcoded object name like.

```
exercise0: {
  // exercise info
}
```

but this means when it gets to redux I need to grab the data via `action.workout.exercise0` which is not great or scalable

Comment: try with fieldArray https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/fieldarray. if it is useful for your application and if you don't able to implement this let me know I'll answer it.

Comment: @Dhaval Hi Dhaval. I did see this but wasn't sure on the exact implementation. would you be able to start me off?

Comment: @Dhaval any chance of a demo? :D